# Como remover o atributo da imagem?

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma `img` dentro de um `a` e quero remover a imagem, mas não consigo. Estou usando o jQuery.

HTML:

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55" class="whats-footer" target="_blank"><img src="imagens/whats.png" class="img-js" alt=""></a>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
                $('a').removeClass('whats-footer');
                $('a').removeAttr('img');
            }
        });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cara a img não é um atributo do link, e sim um elemento dentro do link

Para remover a imagem que está no link vc pode simplesmente faz `$('a > img').remove();`

```html
<a class="whats-footer" target="_blank">
<img src="https://unsplash.it/200/200" class="img-js" alt="">
</a>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $('a').removeClass('whats-footer');
            $('a > img').remove();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: opa, valeu. comecei faz pouco tempo nesse ramo de javascript e comecei a mexer com jquery também... então não sei muito sobre isso kkk

Comment: @FelipeMoreira Sem problemas meu caro, uma dica importante que vou te dar é estudar logo sobre os seletores, pare entender pq o `'a > img'` funciona e como ele funciona. Não são muito os seletores, e vc vai precisar dele direto. então estude logo essa parte que vai te ajudar em tudo!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o `.remove();` desta forma:

```
$(".img-js").remove();
```

> [Jquery Remove() e Empty()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_remove.asp)

No exemplo utilizei a `classe` da imagem para a seleção, já que não possuía um `ID`, mas é recomendado utilizar o `ID`, pois caso possuir várias imagens daquela classe, todas serão removidas.

Comment: hmmm, eu costumo usar classes msm kkkk... raramente uso ids. seu método também deu certo e ajudou bastante, vlw.

Comment: Considere começar a usar IDs com maior frequência, pelo motivo que citei na resposta ;). Fico feliz que a resposta te ajudou, agradeceria se desse um _up_ na minha resposta. Obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Você não tem acesso ao HTML ? por que só nao exclui a img ?

Enfim, vc tbm pode tirar ela com CSS

```
a[href='https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55'] img {
     display:none;
}
```

Comment: Imagino que ele queira tirar a imagem em _tempo de execução_ pelo script, não remover por completo a imagem do código.

Comment: hmm entendo, sendo assim não tenho uma solução